# jar file doesn't do anything when executed (VSCode)

Tags: java, jar

Here I have a short program, which I would like to export as a .jar file. When I use VSCode's "Export Jar..." option (and select `Test` as the main class), it creates the jar file without any errors, but when I run it (by double clicking), nothing happens. When I run the code from within VSCode however, it works as expected (the window shows up and says "Hello World").
Here's my code:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                    frame.setSize(600, 400);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello World!"));
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run your java program (when it is compiled in a `jar` file) you need to do the following:

```
java -cp your-jar-name.jar Test
```

`Test` is a full name (including package name) of your class with `main` method.

If `Main-Class` is defined in manifest your can do also this

```
java -jar your-jar-name.jar
```

Double click won't work if you click on `jar` file in some operating systems. You can use `.sh` script in Linux or `.bat` script in Windows and click on this script.

Comment: In Windows systems, after installing an Oracle JDK, the file extension "jar" is registered for being run with `java`. So double-clicking usually works.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose He says nothing about his OS. And if he runs and nothing happens, then either he uses another OS or main class is not defined in his jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the jar with the following command:

```
java -jar jar-file-name.jar
```

Comment: So the problem isn't the jar file itsself but my way of trying to execute it? In other words, does this mean that double-clicking a .jar file doesn't really have any purpose?

Comment: @WeinSim It has purpose only when jar extension is registered in OS for running with java virtual machine. However, it can be done only if you jar has manifest where `Main-Class` is defined. Think this way, VM must know what class it should execute firstly. But how can it know it? That's why `Main-Class` is required. At the same time double click on jar is used very rarely, because often you need to pass a lot of parameters to VM. So, you use command line or scripts. For details see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What the OS usually does when you doubleclick an 'executable jar' is to run

```
javaw -jar jar-file-name.jar
```

`javaw` is the 'windowed' version of Java, meaning there is no terminal window where console messages are printed but the application would show it's own windows. That seems to not happen in your case.

To troubleshoot, open a terminal window, cd to the directory containing your jar and execute

```
java -jar -jar-file-name.jar
```

Now on the console you can see if errors occurred. But be aware the difference between some jar file and an executable jar file is the META-INF/MANIFEST file. In that `java -jar ...` finds the information which main class to run, and that may be different from what you run in the IDE.